# замена каждого второго пробела словом

Tags: python, for, replace

Так звучит задача: Преподаватель курса прочитал статью британских учёных, в которой написано, что слова-паразиты и дефекты дикции улучшают восприятие материала аудиторией. У преподавателя есть конспект лекции (по иностранному языку) , помогите ему модифицировать текст конспекта, вставив ", ага, " (без кавычек) между каждыми двумя подряд идущими словами.

пытался как-то реализовать через цикл for, не не додумался как.

моя наработка:

`text = input('введите лекцию')`

`(print(text.replace(' ', '~')))`

Answer (score 0):

1. разложить текст на список слов через `split`
2. собрать заново список слов в текст через `join`, где в качестве разделителя использовать

> ", ага, " (без кавычек)

Comment: сложность заключается в том, чтобы вписать "ага" через один пробел

Comment: Ну так разделите на слова, затем пары слов выделите или в цикле сами или через zip и срезы [:2] и [1:2], а пары слов уже ререз join с нужным разделителем а ещё можно рекурсивно делить на 3 куска только через split и соединять пробелом и разделителем